# Variable length format string in c

Tags: c, string

I want to align a text with the help of a variable using the `.*` format specifier.

Ideally I wanted a space of `100` length with `Some Text Here` written and then the `|` sign. But this doesn't seem to work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int prec = 100; // Assume this value to be calculated somehow and not a constant
    char s[20] = "Some Text Here";
    printf("%.*s", prec, s);
    printf("|");

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this so?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try this `printf("%100s", s);`, is that what you want?

Comment: @IrAM what if `prec` is not a constant that I already know?

Comment: @Developer what does your output look like

Comment: Your code is almost correct, you just need `%*s`, not `%.*s`

Comment: Replace `%.*s` with `%*s` (right aligned) or `%-*s` (left aligned)

Comment: @aragaer what is the `.` for? Or when is it used?

Comment: Just number is "field width", while number after '.' is "precision". These two have different meanings (and can be used together). See `man 3 printf` for details.

Comment: @Developer look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is, that you try to do a precision like with a float (n decimal places). That won't work with a string.
You will need to do `%*s`, not `%.*s`